# Angular Formly ui grid with gridOptions

Tags: angular-ui-grid, angular-formly

Following the  [very basic example of how to use the UI Grid with angular-formly](http://jsbin.com/doguba/6/edit?html,js,output)

I am attempting to add filtering to the grid, but unsure how to wire in gridOptions.

[Tutorial: 103 Filtering](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/103_filtering)

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
    enableFiltering: true,
    onRegisterApi: function(gridApi){
    $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
}

<div id="grid1" ui-grid="gridOptions" class="grid"></div>
```

With Formly ui-grid is set to something completely different

```
  app.run(function(formlyConfig) {
    formlyConfig.setType({
      name: 'ui-grid',
      template: '<div ui-grid="{ data: model[options.key] }" ui-grid-auto-    resize ui-grid-pagination ui-grid-selection ui-grid-edit ui-grid-row-edit></div>',
  wrapper: ['bootstrapLabel', 'bootstrapHasError']
   });

});
```

How do I get the Formly ui grid to use the gridOptions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out -

```
app.run(function (formlyConfig) {
    formlyConfig.setType({
        name: 'ui-grid',
        template: '<div ui-grid="{ enableFiltering: true, data: model[options.key]}" ui-grid-auto-resize ui-grid-pagination ui-grid-selection ui-grid-edit ui-grid-row-edit></div>',
        wrapper: ['bootstrapLabel', 'bootstrapHasError']
    });
});
```